# How to solve problems with odd numbers as HTML-canvas size?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm working with the HTML-canvas-element.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('c');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
ctx.rect(0, 0, canvas.width / 3, canvas.height / 3);
ctx.fill();
ctx.closePath();

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
ctx.rect(canvas.width / 3, 0, canvas.width / 3, canvas.height / 3);
ctx.fill();
ctx.closePath();
```

```html
<canvas id="c" width="541" height="541"></canvas>
```

The problem: When I choose an odd number (in this case the prime number 541) as canvas size and draw a rectangle on it (size: 1/3 of the whole canvas).

But this is the result:

[image]

zoomed in:

[image]

As you can see: There is an unwanted line in the between the 2 rectangles. How can I fix this problem?

Rounding the values with `Math.floor()`, `Math.round()` and `Math.ceil()` is (probably) not an option because the sum of the widths of the 3 rectangles must be equal to the width of the canvas.

Comment: What you're asking for is impossible. You want to divide a number which is not a multiple of 3 (in fact, it's prime here) into 3 integer parts without rounding. It *must* be integers because computer screens have discrete pixels. That's just not mathematically possible. Why not store the precise values in variables to reference later, but round them when you draw it so it will draw at integer coordinates? (Note: you may find literary references to sub-pixels; but generally that's just anti-aliasing to fake sub-pixels, which leads to artifacts like what you see here and what you don't want.)

Comment: Rounding the values will work, if you always use either `Math.floor` or `Math.ceil` or `Math.round`. The sum of the widths will be equal to the width of the canvas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are using a HiDPI (High DPI, Retina) mode (with OS-level zoom of more than 100%) while your canvas approach is not HiDPI-compatible.

The solution is to increase the values of the `CANVAS` element’s `width` and `height` *HTML* attributes (or the element’s DOM properties) proportionally with `window.devicePixelRatio` while setting its corresponding *CSS* properties to what you current size is. Then your canvas will be HiDPI compatible and blur-free. That’s what I used in my [web demo](http://tanalin.com/_experimentz/demos/non-blurry-scaling/) of nonblurry integer-ratio scaling:

```js
var pixelRatio = window.devicePixelRatio;

canvas.width  = 541 * pixelRatio;
canvas.height = 541 * pixelRatio;

canvas.style.width  = '' + 541 + 'px';
canvas.style.height = '' + 541 + 'px';
```

An alternative approach is to use the [`scale()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/scale) method of context object instead of setting CSS size. That’s what Paul Lewis from HTML5Rocks [recommends](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/canvas/hidpi/):

```js
var pixelRatio = window.devicePixelRatio;

canvas.width  = 541 * pixelRatio;
canvas.height = 541 * pixelRatio;

canvas.getContext('2d').scale(pixelRatio, pixelRatio);
```

Answer (score 0):

Works fine if you use the style tag or a css file

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('c');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
ctx.rect(0, 0, canvas.width / 3, canvas.height / 3);
ctx.fill();
ctx.closePath();

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
ctx.rect(canvas.width / 3, 0, canvas.width / 3, canvas.height / 3);
ctx.fill();
ctx.closePath();
```

```css
.canvas {
    width: 541px;
    height: 541px;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="c" class="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: This is weird and interesting. Why does this work but the hardcoded width/height doesn't? Especially since mathematically, it shouldn't even be possible?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you like this solution but you could use Math.floor() only on `x2`

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('c');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
ctx.rect(0, 0, canvas.width / 3, canvas.height / 3);
ctx.fill();
ctx.closePath();

// use here to make sure that the start position of the secound rect is right
var x2 = Math.floor(canvas.width / 3);

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
ctx.rect(x2, 0, canvas.width / 3, canvas.height / 3);
ctx.fill();
ctx.closePath();
```

```html
<canvas id="c" width="541" height="541"></canvas>
```